# Anylogic transitions - Rate condition

Tags: anylogic

I was trying to create a transition between two states with a rate logic: I want that event to happen x times randomly, but only for a limited model time interval (for example from 1 pm to 00 am model time, to specify that this event CAN happen only in this range of time).
Do you have any way to suggest?
Thanks a lot,
P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the transition from rate to message with a particular message as follows:

[image]

Then, create a function that returns a double value. The body of the function should be:

```
if( time() < x )
  return 0;

else if( time() >= x && time() < y )
  return rate;

else
  return 0;
```

Of course replace `x` and `y` with the start time and end time of the time range during which the rate is not 0 and replace `rate` with the desired rate.

[image]

Then create an event of trigger type rate. In the rate field write `function()`. In the action field write:

```
if( time() >= x && time() < y )
  send( "rate", this);
```

This last condition before the action of sending the message is important in case the event was scheduled slightly after the range. An event might be schedule a second before the end of the range for a second after the range ends... So we are making sure this is addressed and avoided.

Comment: I did everything as you told me, writing this function:

`if(getHourOfDay() >= 21 && getHourOfDay() <= 7)
return 2;
//return bernoulli(0.8);
else
return 0;`

My aim is to have a rate of 2 during the time interval from 21 to 7 in the morning.
The event I created remains always not scheduled and never triggers.
What could be wrong?

Comment: I think you switched the signs? Greater or equal to 21 means 21, 22, 23 and 24. Less or equal to 7 means 7, 6, 5, etc. So your condition will never be true.

Comment: Actually no, I see what you're doing. Just change the && to II. The condition is OR not AND.

Comment: You're right. I meant the OR condition.. that's my fault. Thanks a lot!